# R ggplot: eliminating empty date range from time series plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

On the bottom image, I have a graph produced by this code:

```
library(lubridate)
shangPM$date <- with(shangPM, ymd_h(paste(year, month, day, hour, sep= ' ')))

ggplot(data = shangPM, aes(x = date, y = PM_US.Post)) + 
geom_line()
```

However, there is four years shown on my x-axis with no data, making the graph look weird. I tried using xlim and coord_cartesian, but this does not seem to be working well with my date variable (maybe I'm wrong?) 
A bit of a noob here - can someone help me zoom in on only the dates I have data for for my plot?

Here is my error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

[image: Time Series Photograph]

Comment: Have you tried `scale_x_continous` or `scale_x_discrete`?

Comment: when you say you tried using xlim and coord_cartesian, what did you actually try to put in?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry, I added the full graph code on here.